# Negate Javascript Regex Pattern

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex, ng-tags-input

I have following Regex Pattern: `[^\u0001-\u00FF]`. With that I validate a user input not containing invalid characters like "€" and so on.

```
var utfRegex: RegExp = new RegExp('[^\u0001-\u00FF]');
return !utfRegex.test(userInput);
```

Now I use the tags-input component and need to validate the user input. So I need to pass a Regex, which works the other way around.

What's the easiest way, to turn this Regex around?

Comment: Remove the negation `^` i.e `[\u0001-\u00FF]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Once I do that I can input everything. :/

Comment: What is your objective? To ensure that the `userInput` _contains only_ invalid characters like `€`? Or the other way round?

Comment: To ensure that the `userInput` contains _only valid characters_, try: `^[\u0001-\u00FF]+$` and change `!utfRegex.test` to `utfRegex.test`. To ensure that it contains _only invalid characters_, use: `^[^\u0001-\u00FF]+$` and change `!utfRegex.test` to `utfRegex.test`

Answer (score 1):

**Allow only Valid Characters:**

To ensure that the `userInput` contains *only valid characters* (range ASCII 0 - 255), regex:

```
`^[\u0001-\u00FF]+$`
```

- `^` and `$` as start and ending anchor
- `[\u0001-\u00FF]+` matches one or more characters belonging to ASCII Range 0 - 255.

also change `!utfRegex.test` to `utfRegex.test`.

Code:

```
var utfRegex: RegExp = new RegExp('^[\u0001-\u00FF]+$');
return utfRegex.test(userInput);
```

**Allow only Invalid Characters:**

To ensure that input contains *only invalid characters*,

```
`^[^\u0001-\u00FF]+$`
```

- `^` and `$` as start and ending anchor
- `[^\u0001-\u00FF]+` matches one or more characters **not** belonging to ASCII Range 0 - 255.

also don't forget to change `!utfRegex.test` to `utfRegex.test`

Code:

```
var utfRegex: RegExp = new RegExp('^[^\u0001-\u00FF]+$');
return utfRegex.test(userInput);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is just taking the symbol format as string. So you must convert them to special characters.

```
var str = unescape(encodeURIComponent('(?!\u0001-\u00FF)'));
var utfRegex = new RegExp(str);
var x = utfRegex.test(userInput);

if(x) { // you can add extra condition if you want there should be an input userInput.length > 0
    // no invalid characters
} else {
    // contains invalid characters
}
```